# SMS payment solution

Tags: api, sms, payment-gateway, payment

I want to integrate a SMS payment solution for my website. I will be offering some premium content and as the prices are not high (1, 3, 5 or 10 Euros) and I would want to use a SMS payment solution.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any providers.

I want the service to provide an API so that the user never has to leave my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few `services` out there that provide you with this type of `feature`. Although, as this involves money you'll most likely need to contact one of the `services` before you can get an idea of the `APIs` and pricing.

I did find a couple of `services` that seem to offer something similar to what you are looking for.

**Some services I found**

- http://www.boku.com/merchants/features/
- http://www.daopay.com/business/how-it-works.php
- http://www.smsteknik.se/prodinfo/smspay_eng.asp

Keep in mind that these are not recommendations, and you should do your own research to determine which SMS provider is the most appropriate for you.

Comment: I think Zaypay is the perfect solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: Zaypay link seems to be dead.